# Binary Search with Strings

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have an object array and I want to search the date / day property (user decides) by using binary search.

**EDIT: I read the SharesArray[mid].Date values (and day values) from a text file and examples are: 05/02/2015, 14/10/2014.The searchString value would be gained from the user but would be in the same format as the date values. **

This is my first attempt so I am just trying the date property:

```
int high, low, mid;
high = SharesArray.Length - 1;
low = 0;

while (low <= high)
{
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (String.Compare(SharesArray[mid].Date, searchString, true) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (String.Compare(SharesArray[mid].Date, searchString, true) > 0)
    {
        high = mid - 1;
    }
    else if (String.Compare(SharesArray[mid].Date, searchString, true) < 0)
    {
        low = mid + 1;
    }
```

I have also tried the last else if statement as just else and that doesn't make any difference.

Also, does it matter what way round string1 and string2 are in the String.Compare part?

Comment: The order of strings in your String.Compare is irrelevant.

Comment: Could you please show us how `Date` is defined in `SharesArray` and give us an example of what value `searchString` could be and what possible values `SharesArray[mid].Date` could be?

Comment: I thought so too but when I used a breakpoint and watched the flow of control it went to different elements in my array when I swapped them.

Comment: I have edited for you John

Comment: @Steve The order in the `Compare` call is most definitely **not** irrelevant and the `mid` calculation is correct, although it is potentially vulnerable to an overflow, so `mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1)`  would be better

Comment: @EmmaD A question and a remark (1) is your input array sorted before you start with the binary search? (2) you should try to work with `DateTime` objects if you want to compare dates, not strings. From the example you mentioned (05/02/2015, 14/10/2014), using string comparison will say that "05/02/2015" < "14/10/2014".

Comment: @Alex can you elaborate on why the order matters? All it's doing is comparing 2 String parameters, String1 and String2

Comment: @Alex (1) Yes, it is sorted in order in the text file. and (2) I have also tried to find out how to do that but didn't come up with anything. How can I compare DateTime objects with the searched for date?

Comment: @Steve, lets consider an example with integers: search x = 5 in y: {1, 5, 7, 9, 15}. lo = 0, hi = 4, mid = 2. then [a] compare(x, y[mid]) = -1, but [b] compare(y[mid], x) = 1. This results in [a] lo = 2 + 1 = 3, [b] hi = 2 - 1 = 1. In case [a] we now have taken the wrong branch, and will never find the matching element 5.at index 1.

Comment: @Alex I think I was misunderstanding her question then - I thought she was asking if the ordering of the parameters mattered ASIDE from her code. Obviously it needs to be built around her logic, but the ordering of strings for the function itself is completely arbitrary, the returned values will just be different (as your example shows)

Comment: @Emma, objects of type `DateTime` have a member function `Compare` that allows you to perform comparison between two dates. The other thing you will have to do, is to convert the strings that you read from the text file to `DateTime` objects. You can do this with `DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` And you will need to convert the `searchString` to a `DateTime` as well in the same manner.

Comment: @Alex your suggestion works perfectly thank you very much!

Comment: @EmmaD I am glad that you were able to solve it.

Comment: @Alex Probably worth wrapping this up into an answer for future generations.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing an answer from the Q&A in the comments of the question, with a bit of additional context.

For binary search, there are a few ingredients you need to take care of

1. The input array to the binary search function must be sorted.
2. Given the algorithm you have implemented, they must be sorted in ascending order.
3. You must have a three-way comparison function, that for `compare(lhs, rhs)` returns: `< 0` if `lhs < rhs`, `> 0` if `lhs > rhs` and `0` if `lhs == rhs`.
4. The order of the arguments in the `compare` function matters, if you switch them, you will be taking the wrong branch and changing the upper search bound instead of the lower, or the other way around.
5. For your implementation, you had the order correct, with `lhs` : `SharesArray[mid].Date` and `rhs` = `searchString`.
6. Because you are comparing dates, you need to use the `DateTime.Compare` function, and convert your date strings to `DateTime` instances, using `DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. With a string comparison you would get wrong results such as `"05/02/2015" < "14/10/2014"`.

And then there is one more anecdotal remark to make (see [here](http://googleresearch.blogspot.nl/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)):

The calculation of the pivot value `mid` is susceptible to integer overflow. If you calculate it as

```
mid = (low + high) / 2;
```

then `low + high` could become larger than fits in an integer.

The preferred way of calculating `mid` is therefore

```
`mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);`.
```

Comment: @EmmaD Since Alex's answer from the comments worked for you probably, for the benefit of the future generations, it's worth to accept this summary as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered LINQ?

```
var searchIndex = SharesArray
    .Select(s => s.Date)
    .ToList()
    .BinarySearch(searchString);
```

Comment: I am trying not to use the BinarySearch in built method

Comment: @EmmaD anything you're trying to achieve should be mentioned in the question.